# How to Serialize correctly a Map with jackson and make it fail if the json strcuture is not a Map?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having issues trying to parse an object in my app using Jackson 2.9.4

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class EsQuery {

  @JsonProperty("_source")
  @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = MapSerializer.class)
  private final Map<String,List<String>> fields;
  @JsonProperty
  private final Map<String, Object> aggs;
  @JsonProperty
  private final Map<String, Object> query;

@JsonCreator
public EsQuery(@JsonProperty("_source") Map<String,List<String>> fields, @JsonProperty("aggs") Map<String, Object> aggs, @JsonProperty("query")
  Map<String, Object> query) {
    this.fields = (MapUtils.isEmpty(fields) ? null : fields);
    this.aggs = (MapUtils.isEmpty(aggs) ? null : aggs);
    this.query = (MapUtils.isEmpty(query) ? null : query);
  }
}
```

Basically, i'm trying to serialize an EsQuery instance from this json:

```
{
    "_source": {},
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [],
            "filter": []
        }
    },
    "aggs": {}
}
```

The error that thows is this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer has no default (no arg) constructor
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.createInstance(ClassUtil.java:553)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializerInstance(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:135)
```

Any ideas? Clearly if I check the class [MapSerializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.9.4/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/MapSerializer.java) it doesn't have any default constructor.

Comment: Why did you add '@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = MapSerializer.class)'? It should work fine without it.

Comment: @Ghokun I did it in order to make it fail when another structure comes instead of the map, (list example). That's because I found a case in which accidentally in the json we define "_source" as a list. Obviously the map is empty, and then the next items ("query" and "aggs") failed to parse, and return nulls on them, but it didn't throw any exception or anything